# How to auto strip hyperlinks & images in wordpress post

Tags: plugins, posts, users, links, front-end

I creat a post form on front-end for wordpress members by use **DJD Site Post** plugin.
Plugin url: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/djd-site-post/

And now i want to auto strip all hyperlink & images in post when user copy & paste content from other website (with many links).

I use the simple editor in plugin (tinymce editor).

How to auto strip all hyperlinks & images in post befor record to database (or when user click the submit button) by **php functions** or **tinymce functions**  (exclude admin user)?

Here is some code in the plugin i think need to edit: (I'm using case **simple**)

```
// Set editor (content field) style
switch($djd_options['djd-editor-style']){
    case 'simple':
        $teeny = true;
        $show_quicktags = false;
        add_filter( 'teeny_mce_buttons', create_function ( '' , "return array('bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'bullist', 'numlist', 'justifyleft', 'justifycenter', 'justifyright', 'undo', 'redo', 'unlink', 'fullscreen');" ) , 50 );
        break;
    case 'rich':
        $teeny = false;
        $show_quicktags = true;
        break;
    case 'html':
        $teeny = true;
        $show_quicktags = true;
        add_filter ( 'user_can_richedit' , create_function ( '' , 'return false;' ) , 50 );
        break;
}
```

Thanks all for help.
(Sorry if my english is not good.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea to strip link- and image tags from the post content (before you save it) by using the `edit_post_content` filter and the `wp_kses` function:

```
add_filter( 'edit_post_content', 'my_edit_post_content', 10, 1 );
function my_edit_post_content( $content ) { 
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) { // only strip for non-admins
        global $allowedposttags;
        $mytags = $allowedposttags;
        unset($mytags['a']);               // don't allow links
        unset($mytags['img']);             // don't allow images
        $content = wp_kses($content, $mytags);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

where `$allowedposttags` is defined here:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/kses.php#L48